# Real analysis, boundaries question

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be a non empty set of real numbers and let $f,g$ be functions defined on $A$ such that $f$ is bounded above on $A$ and $g$ is bounded below on $A$ . If $f(x)\le g(x) \;\forall\; x \in A$. Prove that $\sup f(x)\le\sup g(x)$.

And what does $f$ is bounded above on $A$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

To say that f is bounded above on $A$ means that there exists a constant $M$ such that $f(x) \le M$ for all $x \in A$. Similarly for $g$. Let $f(A) = \{f(x):x\in A\}$ and $g(A) = \{g(x) : x \in A\}$. Since $A$ is nonempty and both $f$ and $g$ are bounded above on $A$, $f(A)$ and $g(A)$ are nonempty subsets of $R$ that are bounded above. By completeness, $\sup f(A)$ and $\sup g(A)$ exist. Since $f(x) \le g(x) \le \sup g(A)$ for all $x \in A$, $\sup g(A)$ is an upper bound for $f(A)$. Hence $\sup f(A) \le \sup g(A)$.

Comment: Thnks for the quick answer.. What if g is bounded below and . We have to prove sup(f(A))≤inf(g(A))

Comment: You didn't finish: "What if $g$ is bounded below and."

Comment: We have to prove sup(f(A))≤inf(g(A))

Comment: It's not necessarily true that $\sup f(A) \le \inf g(A)$. For let $f(x) = g(x) = x$ and $A = [0,1]$. Then $f$ and $g$ are bounded and $f(A) = g(A) = [0,1]$, but $\sup f(A) = 1 > 0 = \inf g(A)$.

Comment: Mmm .. Your counter example is true enough.. Ill comment if there's any update on the question.. Thnx again for the answer